# google sheets and array formula not working properly

Tags: arrays, google-sheets

I have a sheet that is getting filled out thru a query. I an additional column I need to do some math each time a row is added. The array formula is expanding but it just repeats the sum from the first row, not using the new data.

=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ISBLANK(B14:B),"$0.00",SUM(B14+C14)/G14))

same problem on this one:

={INDEX(Crew!$AT$12:$AZ$47, MATCH($I14,Crew!$AT$12:$AT$47, 0), MATCH($E14, Crew!$AT$12:$AZ$12, 0))}

Both formulas work with out the array.

Comment: I have published an answer regarding first formula.  For the second one, could you share a spreadsheet with sample data and expected results, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ARRAYFORMULA` repeats the same values because the internal part should also refer to multiple rows. However, it will not work properly with `SUM`. It is easier to use `MAP` and `LAMBDA` to process values row by row:

```
=MAP(
  B14:B,
  C14:C,
  G14:G, 
  LAMBDA(
    s_1,
    s_2,
    d,
    IF(ISBLANK(s_1), "$0.00", (s_1 + s_2)/d)
  )
)
```

Comment: as is that one sums everything in all the cells. It works properly as:                                            =ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ISBLANK(B14:B),"$0.00",SUM(B14+C14)/G14:G))

Comment: @Dean You are right: `SUM` interferes with `ARRAYFORMULA`.  However, `=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ISBLANK(B14:B),"$0.00",SUM(B14+C14)/G14:G))` will not work as well: it will use only value of `B14+C14` for every row.  I have updated the answer with a different solution.

Comment: ok, I see that it looked like it worked but the math definitely does not check out. I tried your new formula. however got this result:  #REF! Result was not automatically expaned. Please insert more rows(13)

Comment: @Dean Try now.  The formula was generic for all rows of the sheet.  Updated it to start from row 14.

Comment: ok great! That seems to work. Ill do some more checking with the math but it seems good.   I think i will have a hard time posting sample sheets of the other. I will have to recreate them with sample data.

Comment: one side effect is that the empty rows, the ones at the bottom of the sheet where the query has not inserted data yet have the annoying #DIV/0

Comment: @Dean You can wrap the internal formula with `IFERROR` like this: `IFERROR(IF(ISBLANK(s_1), "$0.00", (s_1 + s_2)/d), "$0.00")`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another solution:

```cpp
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(IF(ISBLANK(B14:B),0,(B14:B+C14:C)/G14:G)))
```

Instead of hardcoding `"$0.00"`, it's best practice to use the number `0` and format the cell as currency.